# Dot replaced by underscore while building query string from array

Tags: php, query-string

I'd like to know why the dot is replaced by an underscore during this manipulation :

```
$s = http_build_query([
    "!~.var" => "",
]);

$a = parse_str($s, $r);

echo $s;

print_r($r);
```

prints :

```
%21%7E.var=

Array
(
    [!~_var] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) — Parses the string into variables

[Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) do not allow having dots inside their name.

`$hello.world = 'hello world';` <-- would be illegal.

`$hello_world = 'hello world';` <-- is legal

Comment: Ok but, $hello!world and $hello~world not allowed too, but not corrected during parse_str?..

Comment: Correct, but this will be escaped. `! => %21` and `~ => %7e`. The dot won't be escaped. This is a combination between escaping URL elements and variable name. Also see the [comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#118008).